# wpf draw multiple curve by order with animation

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to create an animation like when we use Touch ID to scan fingerprint,it draw part fingerprint,and finally generate an complete fingerprint image,
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z778m.gif)
The part of fingerprint svg path like this:

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Name="Path1">
           <Path.Data>
               <GeometryGroup >
                   <PathGeometry Figures="M211, 161 C 208, 133 224, 117 242, 114 C 257, 112 285, 118 293, 151 C 301, 191 295, 254 256, 296"></PathGeometry>
                   <PathGeometry Figures="M268, 199 C 271, 164 263, 136 246, 141 C 229, 147 242, 172 241, 199 C 239, 226 224, 257 211, 269"></PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M250, 155 C 255, 171 260, 204 247, 234"></PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M207, 321 C 226, 310 262, 281 275, 237"></PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M301, 280 C 320, 245 327, 200 323, 165"></PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry Figures="M228, 384 C 238, 380 262, 365 277, 353"></PathGeometry>
                </GeometryGroup>
            </Path.Data>
```

So how can I draw fingerprint lines dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

```
PathFigureCollection pathFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();

// Create figures making up the fingerprint
PathFigure pathFigure = new PathFigure();

...

pathFigureCollection.Add(pathFigure);

...

PathGeometry pathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
pathGeometry.Figures = pathFigureCollection;

Path1.Data = pathGeometry;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer，I had make the figures,my trouble is I don't know how to draw the path with animation which just like we use a pen to draw the path,I want to show the track to draw the path,like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/z778m.gif